# Convert xsl - fo to pdf

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, xsl-fo

I have an XSL-FO file and data is available in xml/json formats. I wanted to create a pdf using this xsl structure.

Can anyone suggest any open source libraries for conversion? I want it to be done at the C# level.

Note: I tried converting to html but as it is xsl-fo file I can't get the alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using [fo.net](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=fonet) and it worked for me,
here is the sample code

```
            string lBaseDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("e:\thermalpdf.xsl");
            XslCompiledTransform lXslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            lXslt.Load("e:\thermalpdf.xsl");
            lXslt.Transform("e:\billingData1.xml", "books1.fo");
            FileStream lFileInputStreamFo = new FileStream("books1.fo", FileMode.Open);
            FileStream lFileOutputStreamPDF = new FileStream("e:\response2.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            FonetDriver lDriver = FonetDriver.Make();
            lDriver.BaseDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(lBaseDir);
            lDriver.CloseOnExit = true;
            lDriver.Render(lFileInputStreamFo, lFileOutputStreamPDF);
            lFileInputStreamFo.Close();
            lFileOutputStreamPDF.Close();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Apache FOP (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) tool. It can generate PDF document from XSL-FO input.

From the C# it is possible to start Apache FOP process pointing it to the XSL-FO file (or use stdin, so you don't have to use any temporary files). After process exists you get PDF file (in file on disk or stdout).

For start you can make Apache FOP read XSL-FO file and write PDF file to disk, for that use `Process` class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8):

Draft code snippet (may contains errors but it should be a good start for you):

```
Process.Start("C:\\path\\to\\fop input_xsl-fo.xml output.pdf").WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I tried this thing with the available sample codes, but it's not working. can you help me with a good sample code.

Comment: Please share information of what you tried, what goes wrong, etc. It will be a lot easier for us to help you

Comment: i tried this one  [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/lszk/archive/2012/10/13/using-apache-fop-from-.net-level.aspx) but there is some problem with the references and i'm not getting the exact way to use it.

Comment: It is much easier to use `Process` class and run Apache FOP as separate process.

Comment: can you give me a sample code or any reference so that i can work on that

Comment: my problem is with making **Apache FOP read XSL-FO file** not about writing it to PDF

Comment: Please share code you are running and what is happening. Now we can just guess what you are doing and what is not working.

Comment: What if i have to deploy my c# code as function app..how should I call Fop.bat file in serverless environment

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your project is a `.Net Core` project, but I have created a pure port of `Apache FOP version 2.8` that runs in `.Net Core`. Check it out:

https://github.com/sorcerdon/FOP.NetCore

Here is the nuget:

[image: NuGet version (FOP.NetCore)]

Since this is a pure port, that means that it can do anything that Apache FOP can do.

Comment: in my xslt there is reference to exsl.org for extension objects like date-time..in this case this Fop.netcore is not working as XslCompiledTransform in c# is not able to transform xsl